# How to represent PrimaryKeyRelatedField as field name on the front-end? Currently getting a ValueError

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This is my models:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    alphaNumNoSpaces = RegexValidator(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$', 'Only letters and numbers are allowed. There should no spaces.')
    alphaSpaces = RegexValidator(r'^[a-zA-Z ]+$', 'Only letters and spaces are allowed.')

    locationName = models.CharField(max_length=80, unique=True, validators=[alphaSpaces])
    locationCode = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True, validators=[alphaNumNoSpaces])

class UserExtended(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
```

I am using the default Django User model. This is my UserSerializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # Used source because I want the front-end to receive the location name
    # and not the pk value.
    location = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source='userextended.location.locationName', queryset=Location.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'email', 'location',)
        read_only_field = ('location')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            email = validated_data['email'],
            username = validated_data['username'],
            password = validated_data['password'],
        )
        print(validated_data['userextended']['location'])
        UserExtended.objects.create(user=user, location=validated_data['userextended']['location'])
        return user
```

The problem is, when I send this data to the back-end to create a User object:

```
Location.objects.create(locationName = 'My Location', locationCode = 'ML')

data = {'username': 'a', 'password': 'a', 'email': 'a@hotmail.com', 'location': '1'}
```

I get an error saying:

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "{'locationName': <Location: Location object>}": "UserExtended.location" must be a "Location" instance.
```

and this error traces back to this line:

```
UserExtended.objects.create(user=user, location=validated_data['userextended']['location'])
```

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a `SlugRelatedfield` instead of a `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` because `locationName` isn't the `Location` primary key.

Comment: So what you're saying is that I should do: `location = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='locationName', source='userextended.location.locationName', queryset=Location.objects.all())`? And then on the front-end, I have to submit the location name (rather than the locations pk value) when submitting a form?

Comment: source='userextended.location' because you want the object, not just the name